# How to write unit test for http with httpheaders in Angular 2 Karma Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I try to make some tests for my service. Which are mostly Rest-calls. But some of my Rest-calls have HttpHeaders. How can I make a test including the header parameters?

I want to make a test on this:

```
public getAllNodes(): Observable<any> {
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'someTokenABC');
    headers = headers.append('subscriptionId', 'aaa111');
    headers = headers.append('organizationId', 'bbb222');
    return this.http.get('https://someUrl/getall', {headers: headers, observe: 'response'})
      .map(response => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

This is my test so far:

```
describe('#getAllNodes', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: MyService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [MyService]
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(MyService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should return an Observable<any>', () => {
    var dummyNodes = [{
          "contentId": "111-222-333",
          "title": "some title",
          }];

    service.getAllNodes().subscribe(nodes => {
      expect(nodes.length).toBe(1);
      expect(nodes).toEqual(dummyNodes);
   });

   const req = httpMock.expectOne('https://someUrl/getall');
   expect(req.request.method).toBe("GET");
   req.flush(dummyNodes);
   httpMock.verify();
});
});
```

In my case I get this error: 
Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://someUrl/getall", found none.

But I guess this has something to do with the httpheader. I am not adding this because I don't know how to include them in the test.

Anyone know how I can solve this test?

EDIT:

Or can I do something like this? (nodes is an array of nodes and is filled up when getAllNodes() is called)

```
describe('#getAllNodes', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: MyService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [MyService]
    });

    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(MyService);
  });

  it('should have no nodes at startup', () => {
    expect(service.nodes.length).toBe(0);
  })

  it('should have more than 1 node', () => {
    service.getAllNodes();
    expect(service.nodes.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  })

});
```

But here on the last test it returns 0 hits. Even though service.getAllNodes() should return multiple hits.

Comment: Where are you passing the `httpMock` in your test case? When is its `request` method called? I see you adding the expected call, yet which service is supposed to be using it?

Comment: Basically, the error states: This mock has not been interacted with as expected, hence it throws. But where in your code do you want to use the httpMock?

Comment: Well, I want to test if I get any response from the getAllNodes(). Obiously I am doing something wrong here/not understanding the test process.

Answer (score 0):

Use spyon for fake service call. also import of operator.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';



describe('#getAllNodes', () => {
it('should return an Observable<any>', () => {
  const dummyNodes = [{
        "contentId": "111-222-333",
        "title": "some title",
        }];
  spyOn(httpMock, 'get').and.returnValue(of(dummyNodes));
  service.getAllNodes().subscribe(nodes => {
    expect(nodes.length).toBe(1);
    expect(nodes).toEqual(dummyNodes);
 });

 expect(httpMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url, paramsObj);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't test anything. It just sets up mocks and tests that the mocks have been interacted with as set up.

Answer (score 0):

The only "problem" I see is that it is more recommended to use rxjs `pipe' as :

```
    return this.http.get('https://someUrl/getall', { headers: headers, observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        return response;
      }),
    );
```

:p